# Desktop application vs web application

Tags: php, web-applications

I have a custom accounting + user specific needs desktop application (which i developed using delphi 7 + mysql and over 20 users are actively using the application), it has bills, personnels, banks, clients, reports etc...
client requested an updated version but he wants that version run as a web application

I want to use php + mysql

But i dont know if i can do everything that i did with my desktop application

I want to ask that if i were start to develop a web application version of my desktop application are there major things i cant do on web application

I dont wanna stuck after i am half the way and realise that we cant do what we did on desktop application with web application

Comment: There are so many possible things that you can't do in a web app that this answer could fill a book.   Maybe you could narrow it down to just the things your app actually does?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller my app keeps records in mysql and then list them, and printing is important, local hdd access is important as it is multiuser and some data of user is being keep on the computer they are working on, exports to excel, pdf..., sending smses, reminders etc ...

Comment: @StephenOstermiller when you say there are so many possible things a web app cant do, is that mean like "web app will be weak and it will stuck at some point?"

Comment: Web apps can't take advantage of hardware installed like GPS, scanner, etc.   Web apps can't save to disk locally.    There are many UI paradigms that are hard to replicate.  Google has managed to get spreadsheets and word processors to work reasonably well on the web, so many apps can make the leap.  What does your app actually want to do?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller keep records in mysql, list them, report them, print bills/receipts, keep user preferences, no any relation with any hardware except printing so printers are in use, creating folders for some clients and keeping some image files under this folders, showing/previewing/printing that image files, keeping and using fastreport files to report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your comments and clarifying that you don't need to access hardware.

Everything you say like create reports, keep user preferences etc will be achievable however some things like saving user preference can be achieved with cookies as an example so it'll be different in terms of how to achieve some of the things.

In web apps you'll need to be able to cater for all browsers as that's how you'll be using it most likely.

You'll be able to access it from different screen sized devices such as mobile, tablet and larger screens so you'll want to take into consideration those factors  (not that huge). Look into responsive web design bootstrap does a good job.

You'll need to use javascript to do front end stuff like asynchronous updates/create/sorting etc. Something like jquery has lots of plugins that you can use.

With web apps you'll always need an Internet connection to use. So it'll need a domain name and it'll be public so more susceptible to hacking.

You could overcome some of that by installing it on a local server which every user has access to.

You'll find many classes and even frameworks that are maintained by communities which has bulk of the work and best practices already implemented. You might just need to adapt etc.